# Special characters appear as emoji

Tags: unicode, emoji

I'm developing an Android app with Galaxy S8.

When I write some special characters, they appear to be Galaxy emoji. Things like these: ↔♥◀▶

How can I prevent them from turning into emoji?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically to select between the emoji and the character version you'll have to use a [variation selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block))

> Unicode defines variation sequences for many of its emoji to indicate their desired presentation.
>
> > Emoji characters can have two main kinds of presentation:
> >
> > - an emoji presentation, with colorful and perhaps whimsical shapes, even animated
> > - a text presentation, such as black & white
> >           — Unicode Technical Report #51: Unicode Emoji
>
> Specifying the desired presentation is done by following the base emoji with either U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15 (VS15) for text or U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16 (VS16) for emoji-style.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation

So if you don't want them to be displayed as emojis just attach a VS15 to the end

Comment: your comment is recent one compare to other threads suggesting the same VS15 solution. Hence replying you here.  
This is still rendering as emoji even when VS15 is added. Actual unicode is u2665 (diamond)  and this happens with NOT all devices but some devices with APIs >=23.  
App is already in store play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drulapp.padashri where you can see  screenshot with diamond symbol in crossword gridview which should be white color text but rendering as emoji with other color.